# Why does the UI stop updating countdown after restarting the app while using intent service?

Tags: java, android, service, android-service

I am trying to show a countdown in a textview from a loop inside an Intent Service. I am using the result receiver class for the communication between Intent Service and Activity. It works fine when I start the service for the first time. The textview shows the countdown for each time the loop runs in the service.

But when I close and launch the app again the textview doesn't show the countdown and only shows the hard coded text, while on the other hand the service stills runs in the background.

Here is my code snippet for the MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

 public static final String RECEIVER_INTENT_EXTRA_NAME = "message_receiver_intent_extra";
 private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
 private Intent intent;
 MyIntentService myIntentService;
 public TextView serviceCountdown;
 private Button startButton, stopButton;
 private Handler handler;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();

    myIntentService = new MyIntentService();
    startButton = findViewById(R.id.startServiceButton);
    stopButton = findViewById(R.id.stopServiceButton);

    startButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    stopButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    handler = new Handler();
    serviceCountdown = findViewById(R.id.serviceCountdown);
    MessageReceiver messageReceiver = new MessageReceiver(handler);

    // send intent service
    intent = new Intent(this, MyIntentService.class);
    intent.putExtra(RECEIVER_INTENT_EXTRA_NAME, messageReceiver);

 }

 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {

    if (startButton.equals(v)) {
        ContextCompat.startForegroundService(getApplicationContext(), intent);
    }
    if (stopButton.equals(v)){
        stopService(intent);
    }
 }

 public class MessageReceiver extends ResultReceiver {

    public MessageReceiver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        super.onReceiveResult(resultCode, resultData);
        if (resultCode == 1 && resultData != null){
            final String countdown = resultData.getString("countdown");

            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    serviceCountdown.setText(countdown);
                }
            });
        }
    }
 }
}
```

And here is my code for the Intent Service Class

```
public class MyIntentService extends IntentService {

private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "my_channel_id";
private static final String TAG = "MyIntentService";

public MyIntentService() {
    super("MyIntentService");
    setIntentRedelivery(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, notificationIntent,0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("My Service Title")
            .setContentText("This is sample notification text")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_battery)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();
    startForeground(1, notification);
}


@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(@Nullable Intent intent) {

    ResultReceiver resultReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.RECEIVER_INTENT_EXTRA_NAME);
    Log.d(TAG, "onHandleIntent: called");
    synchronized (this) {
        for (int i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.d(TAG, "Service is looping : " + i);

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("countdown", String.valueOf(i));
            resultReceiver.send(1, bundle);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    Log.d(TAG, "onDestroy: called");
    super.onDestroy();
}
}
```

In the real project, my intention is not to using the loop to show a countdown. It is just for testing and debugging purpose.

Comment: When you open app again wait 10s I think the textview will be update again right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Local Broadcast Receiver from your service to activity. Now you getting the ResultReceiver from the MainActivity Intent. When the activity destroyed intents are also destroyed.
Use this Broadcast Receiver code in your service class.

```
LocalBroadcastManager localBroadcastManager = 
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this);
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(INTENT_ACTION_KEY);
        sendIntent.putExtra(DATA_KEY, data);
        localBroadcastManager.sendBroadcast(sendIntent);
```

Get this local broadcast receiver in your activity.

```
  BroadcastReceiver broadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent != null) {
             //Perform your logic.
            }
        }
    };
```

Make sure you register this broadcast when activity starts and unregister it when stop.

```
 @Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver((broadcastReceiver),
            new IntentFilter(INTENT_ACTION_KEY));
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).unregisterReceiver(broadcastReceiver);
    super.onStop();
}
```

Comment: Wow! Nice! It works absolutely fine. Thank you very much for your help. I'm upvoting your answer. Thanks once again.

Comment: I did it. But due to my low reputation, it is not visible publicly. Also, please upvote my question.